# Should this question have been closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My question on Stack Overflow, inquiring about [the reason (if any) for a specific C# coding style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23816144/1001985), was closed as opinion-based.  I disagree, but what do people here think?  Should it be re-opened as is?  Would you vote to re-open if it was re-worded maybe?

My question is basically: one, is there a functional reason for using parentheses in this specific way; two, is it a practical matter of safeguarding against typos that might slip past the compiler; or three, is it purely a matter of style preference?  Any reasons of the first two types would be important to know about.

Notice that I'm not asking "which style is better".  To me, this is not a matter of opinion: either a reason of the first (technical) or second (practical) kind exists, or it does not.  I can see how people might think "opinion-based", because while a positive answer would be definitive, it is too hard to prove an answer in the negative.  But that's why I asked the question: so that programmers with more experience than I have could either produce a technical/practical reason, or answer with confidence "no, it's just stylistic".

Comment: I don't see an issue with your question, and agree it should have been left open. I've cast my vote to reopen it (which was the final one needed to do so). :-)

Comment: I agree you are asking an objective question there. I guess I can see how someone would think it's opinion based, but a close reading reveals its true nature. Bwahahaha... cough.. ;)

Comment: Coding style is personal taste. It is inherently primarily opinion based. What holds true for me, may not hold true for you. Also, you need to be very careful how you word your question. Even if you are a high-rep user, it is expected you do so. It is amusing how many high-rep users ask primarily opinion based questions, but that discussion is not for today. It is better to avoid any kind of sign of "opinion" if you expect a non-opinion based answer or more. I would have personally left out the coding style part, really.

Comment: "or is it some kind of safeguard against typos " formulations like this attract a lot of opinions, and note that the close reason is not about asking for opinions, but about that answers will likely be based on opinions. And here I see potential for opinionated answers. Already the accepted answer is quite opinion colored.

Comment: @lpapp "It is amusing how many high-rep users ask primarily opinion based questions". I've noticed that as well. A possible explanation is that high-rep users are at the level where opinion-based discussion tends to involve fairly educated opinions with strong objective content. I think that there is such a thing as a *good* opinion-based question, but they tend to get lost in the noise of poor opinion-based questions, hence the blanket ban. At least that's my opinion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been noticing a trend.

People don't make the distinction between asking about the pros and cons of a solution, and actually choosing what to do. [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23700598/1348195) is on a question that has 4 close votes and is completely objective.

Objective questions about which of several alternatives in coding is strong where are perfectly on topic in my opinion*. The only opinion based part is which to actually use.

I think the "Opinion Based" close reason should be further clarified (although I admit, it is already clear in my opinion) to reflect that.

<sup>* Note - alternatives does *not* mean libraries, or tools, but rather coding styles, patterns, paradigms or whatever.</sup>